# Is 12px text size in Figma equal to 12sp text size in Android XML layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, figma

In my figma android maket i have a text with 12px text size, which text size should i set for my textview in android app? 12sp or other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the text size in Figma and Android XML layouts are not same.

Pixels in Figma are fixed-size units on a static design canvas. They do not change based on the screen size or resolution.

On the other hand, scale-independent pixels (sp) in Android are flexible units that adjust according to the user's font size settings and the device's screen density.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what should I do in the current situation? What font size should I set?

Comment: it depends on the density of the device. The base density is mdpi (medium density), which is approximately 160dpi so if you considere this as a base density then 1px will be consider as 1sp. For hdpi (high density) screen, which is approximately 240dpi, 1px in Figma would be equivalent to 1.5sp in Android and so on.  

You might need to create different dimen files to support different density devices. And good testing is required on various devices to ensure it properly looks.

Comment: For now you can use direct px value as a sp without any conversion. later you can check and test in different devices and make dimen files for different density and make sure if it looks proper.

Comment: Oh thanks, this is harder than I thought

Comment: You can check official android documents on how to support different screen sizes and also there are lots of guides available on the Medium.